# How to write a loop in R to create multiple different subsets of data based on column names?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

I would like to write a loop to create subsets of data from a large data frame (containing 48 columns total) that can also automatically write out these subsets into .txt files. I will begin by describing the structure I am trying to achieve within each file:

- The first 9 columns should be printed as they are into every subset created from the main file. These are necessary for all files created. Each subset will have 11 columns total.
- The 10th and 11th columns are what will change in each subset. The loop should go through the remaining 39 columns in the original data frame and combine them in all ways possible. So, if the columns' names in the original data set are AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, some example combinations of the subset data would be:

> (first 9 columns) AA BB
>
> (first 9 columns) AA CC
>
> (first 9 columns) AA DD
>
> (first 9 columns) AA EE

- The files should be written out based on the names of the 10th and 11th columns' names. So, the files created by the loop would be:

> AAxBB.txt
>
> AAxCC.txt
>
> AAxDD.txt
>
> AAxEE.txt

I have previously tried to write loops that use column names, but they did not turn out well for me. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070880/looping-through-data-to-set-values-or-variable-as-na-in-r) for an example of how I attempted to write the code. What I am wondering is how to potentially use column names twice as a variable in order to write out the files as I would like to. Is that possible? Would an index system work better? Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I am working out so far:

```
for (i in colnames(data)){
    for (j in colnames(data){
        subset = subset(data, select = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "print(i)", "print(j)"
        write.table(subsetprint(i)&print("x")&print(j), file ="print(i)&print("x")&print(j)", quote = F, row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = " ", na = "-999")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370492/5133721

Comment: Are you aware that `"print(i)"` is just a character string, not a way of printing the value of `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base function `combn` is ideal for this. You can get all combinations 2 by 2 of the remaining column names and call a function on each of those combinations.

First, some data.

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- matrix(rnorm(5*(4+5)), nrow = 5)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

Now the code. Note that I will just keep the first 4 columns common, not 9. And you should change the default value of function `fun` argument `DF = df1` to `DF = yourdata`.

```
first_cols <- 1:4

fun <- function(nms, DF = df1, fc = first_cols){
  cols <- c(names(DF)[fc], nms)
  outfile <- paste(nms, collapse = 'x')
  outfile <- paste(outfile, 'txt', sep = '.')
  write.table(DF[cols], outfile, 
              row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, 
              quote = FALSE, sep = ' ')
  cols
}
combn(names(df1)[-first_cols], 2, fun)
```